# Center RelativeLayout vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/func_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="This is my test string............"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's based on an example from one of t[image]he stack overflow threads. The result is as follows:

I am wrapping the content in the relative layout using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

It doesn't matter if I set the `layout_gravity` as `"center"` or `"center_vertical"`. I can never set this relative layout at the center of the screen (vertically).

Not really sure what I am missing here.

EDIT: See chat from @codeMagic as well; it might help in some cases.

Comment: Adding `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the root LL works. This centers the root's contents

Comment: You meant `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` @codeMagic :)

Comment: No, @Melquiades that doesn't work. That would try to make the root LL centered vertically which it can't because it has a height of `match_parent`. `layout_gravity` moves itself to that position whereas `gravity` moves it's contents to that position

Comment: Ah, you're right, missed that, thanks for explanation @codeMagic

Comment: @codemagic That would center vertical any other elements I have in my linear layout. For example, before the relative layout, if I have an image, it will be centrally vertical as well. This is not desired. :(

Comment: @p0lAris these are things you need to disclose in your post. All we have to go on is what you have shown. There's no way to give a good answer if we don't know your complete situation

Comment: @codeMagic I understand where you are coming from but that is irrespective of what other elements I have in the layout. I simply want the a particular relative layout centered vertically. Not everything else.

Comment: I understand but, again, these are things you need to add. Otherwise, I would have suggested something similar to what @Melquiades has put in an answer. We can't guess at what you might want to add/have left out. Anyway, that answer, I think , should work for you. But do note the reason that gravity isn't working as I commented above

Comment: @codeMagic I am sorry if this is uncomfortable; but I think my question was specific enough about the relative layout. Again, apologies if you think otherwise!

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, I am in the process of replying. That works.

Comment: No worries, it's not uncomfortable for me. I was just trying to help you understand how to get better/more accurate answers. It's just that I could have given you several different answers that would work in several different situations :)

Comment: Sure. I will make it easier for people!! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to change the outer **LinearLayout** to **RelativeLayout**, and then just add this line to the inner **RelativeLayout**:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This does the job.

Comment: If you would care to add the bit about *why* `gravity` and `layout_gravity` aren't working for the OP and *why* your answer works, I could feel good about giving an upvote. I could also then cleanup some, then, obsolete comments :)